# Firebase crashlytics error

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics gives following error while syncing gradle file

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
 > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
```

Comment: In gradle you can use "-s" or "--stacktrace" to see error log, And then you will find the solution.

./gradlew clean build --stacktrace

Comment: this resolve for me : https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1006